# How to upload multiple images/files in angular with laravel api?

Tags: angular, laravel

Hi im trying to upload multiple files at once in angular 8 and laravel api. 
I am able to store single image using this code..
Angular code:

```
    <input type="file" name="image" (change)="uploadImage($event)">
```

```
    uploadImage(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.img = <File>event.target.files[0];
    }
```

```
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('image', this.img, this.img.name);
```

Laravel code:
this is how i move image to a folder and then store name into database..

```
    $img = $request->file('image');
    $image = str_random(10).time().'.'.$img->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destination = 'assets/images/';
    $img->move($destination, $image);
```

How can i do this for multiple files at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i made it work by loops in Angular and as well in Laravel Controller
Idk, if it's a right solution, but i will post this as answer so maybe others benefit from it, below is my code..
HTML

```
    <input type="file" required name="images" (change)="uploads($event)" multiple>
```

Typescript function on change

```
    uploads(event) {
        console.log(event);
         this.docs = <File>event.target.files;
         this.length = <File>event.target.files.length;
   }
```

get formdata

```
    const formdata = new FormData;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                formdata.append('docs'+[i], this.docs[i], this.docs[i].name );
                formdata.append('length', this.length
            }
```

Then send this form data through api..and then in Laravel Controller, i used another loop to move each image into a folder and set a random name, and then add that name to a array.

```
    $length =  $request->length;
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
            $img[$i] = $request->file('images'.$i);
            $image = str_random(10).time().'.'.$img[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destination = 'assets/images/';
            $img[$i]->move($destination, $image);
            $images[] = $image;
            }
```

Then save this array into database using json_encode($images) function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code:

In HTML:

```
<input type="file" (change)="upload($event)" multiple/>
```

In ts

```
    upload(event){

    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        for (let x = 0; x < fileList.length; x++) {
                      formData.append("someFile", fileList[x], fileList[x].name);
                    }
        this.uploadFiles(formData).subscribe();         


    }
uploadFiles(formData: any): Observable<any> {
            const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'api/uploads', formData, {
              reportProgress: true,
              headers: new HttpHeaders()
                .append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')
            });

            return this.http
              .request(req);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think file upload is a weak point in angular, but it can be done by storing input value as [FileList object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList). FileList is not iterable, so if you need to validate, you could convert it to File[] ie. Array.from();

Just send the object/array with a normal http request

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="file" name="image" (change)="uploadImage($event)" multiple>` to take more than one file in input field. In laravel controller make sure to iterate for each file.